# Apply function to each DataFrame row, without returning a Series

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I need to "apply" a function to a `DataFrame` row by row, by taking as input two particular cells of the current row for performing an operation. The function is the following:

```py
def function(x, y):
    z = 2*x*y
    values.append(z)
    return z
```

The problem is that the function shouldn't be really applied, I need only the input values to perform some operations and fill the global list called `values`.
If we suppose the `pd.DataFrame` to be the following:

```py
| col1 | col2 | col3 |
| 2    | 3    | 5    |
| 10   | 12   | 14   |
| ...  | ...  | ...  |
```

I would usually apply the function like this:

```py
df.apply(lambda x: function(x['col2'], x['col3']), axis=1)
```

The problem with `apply` is that the last line of code would create a `pd.Series` and I would actually have in my memory not only the global list `values` that I need for other purposes (I used this list as an example for some other data structure that could be created starting from the function) but also this `Series` that I don't need at all.

How can I apply the function without occupying additional memory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This operation can already be directly vectorized by-row, so you can avoid using `.apply()`, which will be tremendously faster
[Canonical Answer for **How to iterate over rows in a DataFrame in Pandas?**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55557758/4541045)

You won't be able to avoid using memory for the results because they need to go *somewhere*, but you could throw out columns you no longer need before or after performing the calculation

Just keeping the results in a dataframe column (Series) rather than a list of native ints will be a memory savings, but you may find that explicitly setting or reducing the datatypes of your dataframe is a big savings if they're not in their most efficient types already (for example from `int64` to `uint16` or even `uint8` (which will still contain the example values)

```py
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({"col1": [2,10], "col2": [3,12], "col3": [5,4]})
>>> df
   col1  col2  col3
0     2     3     5
1    10    12     4
>>> df["2xy"] = 2 * df["col2"] * df["col3"]
>>> df
   col1  col2  col3  2xy
0     2     3     5   30
1    10    12     4   96
```

Comment: Thank you! But what if the function is more complex, for example, if I have to create a global graph or tree. Is iterating my best shot in that case?

Comment: tbh I'd follow the advice here, trying explicitly to avoid iteration and use an existing method to get what you want, even if you have to transform the input data a little to get that result (because the transformation will also be vectorized, many extremely fast operations are overall much faster than a single very slow operation) https://stackoverflow.com/a/55557758/4541045 .. it's often worth doing both actions on a sample to show the results are the same and the speedup exists, but then recording that you did this research and using the faster method

Answer (score 1):

This seems too simple so I may be missing something, but couldn't you do this in... a loop?

```
def function(x, y):
    z = 2*x*y
    return z

for i, row in df.iterrows():
    values.append(function(row['col2'], row['col3']))
```

Would solve the literal problem you raised of creating a second object aside from `values` in memory to store the results.

Comment: Yes, this was what I would have done as an alternative. But I was searching for a more "pythonic" way, without iterating on the df. Thank you.